# Apache HTTP library not working in API 27

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

I see my `HttpClient`  written in red showing error that `class not found`.

I added in `build.gradle` (app)

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

But does nothing..

I'm using latest version (3) of Android Studio, with targetSdkVersion 27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check inside your SDK Path `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` is available?

```
D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-27\optional\
```

copy that into your Lib folder and add dependancy in your gradle then `compile` it.